# Is this the right way to storing an image in image folder?(in php)

Tags: php

($data is encoded jpg image & then decoding it by following code & trying to store it   in image folder)

```
 $data = base64_decode($data);         //decoded image
 $im = imagecreatefromstring($data); 
 if ($im !== false) 
 {
   header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
   imagejpeg($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'An error occurred.';
 }
 // storing it in image folder on 
 $success = file_put_contents('images/5.jpg',$im);
 echo $success ? $im : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please, try to describe your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

The `$im` variable does not contain the image data, it's an opaque resource that can be used with the gd functions but nothing else. Writing it to a file won't do what you want.

To save an image as JPEG you should use the [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg) function and provide file path as second parameter. Alternatively, if the original image data was already in JPEG format, you can write the `$data` string to the file (in which case, why do you bother decoding it into an image?).

Comment: @ Joni Thank you, but I am getting my original image in byte array format, so I'm decoding it to image and storing it in $data variable (as it would be string stream, I am using imagecreatefromstring(), which helps me to get image from string stream)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @ Joni question was whether I coded it the right way!!

Comment: Anyways, thanks..:) I got solution for this..

Comment: Well no, you didn't code it right way, the explanation is in the answer... Does that answer the question or do you have more doubts? What was the solution by the way?

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this

```
chdir('images');

// and then 

$success = file_put_contents('5.jpg',$im);
```

can you please change your present working directory

check this [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)

Comment: @ Shakti Patel, I tried this, it didn't work!! :(